# Eliminar los títulos de hipervinculos al cargar la web

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que en mi web nada mas cargan se elimine la frase "permanent link to:" de los "title" de todos los hipervínculos a `href` ya que me los esta generando Wordpress y no soy capaz a caparlo, estoy probando con este código pero no me lo hace.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").attr('title').replace('Permalink to', '');
});
</script>>
```

Por otra parte, sí que me funciona este código pero este es para eliminarlo por completo.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").removeAttr("title");
});
</script>
```

Comment: y tienes un ejemplo de las referencias de tu codigo html?

Comment: agrega tu codigo HTML  de como lo tienes para poder darte una mejor respuesta..!!

Comment: simplemente me carga una serie de enlaces a categorias del estilo <a href="urldestino" title="Permanent link to: titulo página">Titulo pagina</a>

Me pone automaticamente ese Permanent link to antes al titulo de la página y es lo que quiero evitar que aparezca.

Comment: tu metodo a buscar es text y despues replace  var miUrl= $("a").text().replace...;  por ultimo $("a").text(miUrl)

Comment: Pese a que puse una respuesta, siempre es de bien el tener el html sobre el que trabajas, porque nuestras respuestas podrán ser mas acertadas. Igualmente, si alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema, márcala como aceptada, para que el resto de usuarios también sepan que esa respuesta funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No creo que sea necesario el uso de `replace`. Usando `attr` y reemplazando el valor actual por una cadena vacía debería bastar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").attr("title", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría A">Categoría A</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría B">Categoría B</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría C">Categoría C</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría D">Categoría D</a>
</div>
```

Recuerda que cuando usas `attr("atributo")` es para obtener el valor del atributo, pero cuando usas `attr("atributo", "valor")` es para setear el valor de dicho atributo.

Si lo que quieres es sacar la parte del título que dice `"Permalink to:"`, lo que puedes hacer es setear el `title` con el contenido del elemento. Es decir:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function(index, element) {
     $(element).attr("title", $(element).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría A">Categoría A</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría B">Categoría B</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría C">Categoría C</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría D">Categoría D</a>
</div>
```

Si quisieras seleccionar todos aquellos que, por ejemplo, están dentro del `<footer></footer>`, podrías hacer algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("footer a").each(function(index, element) {
     $(element).attr("title", $(element).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría A">Categoría A</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría B">Categoría B</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría C">Categoría C</a>
  <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría D">Categoría D</a>
</div>
<footer>
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría J">Categoría J</a>
    <a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoría K">Categoría K</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Pero de esta forma esta haciendo lo mismo que mi segundo codigo que borra el contenido del atributo tittle, yo solo quiero borrar la parte de "Permalink to:" de tal forma que en tu ejemplo si mostrase la letra como el titulo a pasar el ratón por encima.

Comment: @David lo que tu estás haciendo en tu segundo código es eliminar el atributo. Yo solo lo estoy cambiando a una cadena vacía.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que se mantena el resto de la cadena, pero eliminar la parte de la misma que pone "Permanent link to" ya que los title que me estable automatiamente son "Permanent link to: Categoria A" pues quiero que quede de la forma de Categoria A

Comment: @David entiendo. He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto! gracias!

Comment: si quisiera que solo afectara a ciertos enlaces como podría configurarlo? Por ejemplo solo a los que me genera en el footer el wordpress, gracias.

Comment: @David solo tendrías que usar el selector adecuado. He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, genial todo, gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un script muy sencillo en jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
    var texto= $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('title',texto);
    });
})
```

Es muy sencillo. Primero linea lo que hace es esperar a que todo se cargue. Después seleccionamos todos los `<a>` y extraemos su texto con la tercera linea. Y, para finalizar, con la cuarta asignamos el valor del texto a los atributos title.

Aquí funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/Emerita/65avb1sf/3/

Cualquier duda avisa. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario utilizar JQuery para una operación así, bastaría con utilizar [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) y [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) para poder reemplazar el texto deseado, utilizando `replace`

```js
var tagsa = document.querySelectorAll('a')
tagsa.forEach(tag=>{
  //seteamos el valor de title al title actual, reemplazando el texto por vacío
  tag.setAttribute('title',tag.getAttribute('title').replace('Permalink to',''));
})
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoria A">Categoria A</a>
<a href="#" title="Permalink to: Categoria B">Categoria B</a>
```

Si desea con `JQuery` es la misma idea, obtener los enlaces y setear el title con el que tiene actualmente, reemplazando el texto que desee.

```js
$("a").each(function(i,tag) {
  $(tag).attr("title", $(tag).attr('title').replace('Permalink to',''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="Permalink to: A">Categoria A</a>
<a href="#" title="Permalink to: B">Categoria B</a>
```

Comment: Para insertar ese codigo en wordpress seria con las etiquetas <script> y en el head?

Comment: @David donde añadió el código que intentó y expuso en su pregunta. La única diferencia es que no hace falta tener importado JQuery antes. Igual actualicé la opción JQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un `replace` y luego un `trim`.

Recordar que en el `replace` debes de colocar tambien los dos punto `(:)` y el `trim` para eliminar cualquier espacio en blanco.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    var newTitle = $(this).attr("title").replace("Permanent link to:", '').trim();
    $(this).attr("title", newTitle);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría A">Categ. A</a> <br/>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría B">Categ. B</a> <br/>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría Y">Categ. Y</a> <br/>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría Z">Categ. Z</a>
</div>
```

El ejemplo de arriba es siempre y cuando en el `title` despues de los dos puntos difiera del `text` del enlace. Si sabes que el contenido siempre va hacer el mismo, entonces puedes utilizar el `text`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title",$(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría A">Categoría A</a> <br/>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría B">Categoría B</a> <br/>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría Y">Categoría Y</a> <br/>
  <a href="#" title="Permanent link to: Categoría Z">Categoría Z</a>
</div>
```